# Local Variables in viewdidload

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm currently trying to make a program when I create a button, and when I click it its alpha goes to zero. It may seam simple, but its driving me crazy.

You see, in my final project I'm making a lot of buttons so I need to do this **all in code** and **not using story board**.

Heres what I have so far

```
//mediumboard.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface MediumBoard : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *ScrollMedium;
@end
```

And in the implementation

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
UIButton *Button1x1x1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[Button1x1x1  addTarget:self action:@selector(Press1x1x1) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
Button1x1x1.frame = CGRectMake(50,50, 80, 130);
[self.view addSubview:Button1x1x1];
}
```

Up in till now it works fine. It creates the button and displays it on my screen.
However when I try to implement this

```
-(void)Press1x1x1 {
Button1x1x1.alpha = 0;}
```

It gives me the error "Use of undeclared identifier 'Button1x1x1'"

I know its a variable localization problem, and that the variable Button1x1x1 is localized in viewdidload, but I have no idea how to solve this problem. Do I make it global variable? Please remember I can't use the Storyboard.

Additional info: I have no other references to Button1x1x1 in my code, anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a selector that passes the sender as an argument.

```
[button1x1x1 addTarget:self action:@selector(press1x1x1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                                                   //  ^ emphasized
-(void)press1x1x1:(UIButton *)sender {
    sender.alpha = 0;
}
```

---

and you should change your variable names so they start with a lowercase letter. Capital letters should only be used for class names.

Comment: This didn't work, when I implemented it I get a SIGBRT error.

Comment: When did you get a SIGBRT? when it started or when you hit the button?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to declare a global variable, just declare it as an instance variable like so:

```
@interface MediumBoard : UIViewController {
@private
  UIButton *myButton_; // Or Button1x1x1, whatever you want to call it
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *ScrollMedium;
@end
```

Comment: This didn't work, when I implemented it I get a SIGBRT error.